# Google Compute Engine HTTP Load Balancing - Log Files Available?

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are having a weird issue with the HTTP Load Balancing. Is there a way to view log files to troubleshoot why a request would be failing with a (502) Bad Gateway? Like log files or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic from the load balancer to your instances has an IP address in the range of 130.211.0.0/22. When viewing logs on your load balanced instances, you will not see the source address of the original client. Instead, you will see source addresses from this range.

The load balancing configuration automatically creates firewall rules if the instance operating system is a Compute Engine image. If not, you have to create the firewall rules manually by adding the following in your GCE firewall:

```
130.211.0.0/22   tcp:1-5000   Apply to all targets
```

A 502 error can be caused by an unhealthy instance as well. Make sure that your instance is healthy. You can narrow down the issue by trying to Curl your instance's IP address behind the load balancer to check if it returns a correct output.

Comment: George - Thanks for the reply. I will go ahead and accept it but I am not needing to get into the logs anymore. I was trying to find out about the 502 error and come to find out its because Google does not support the Expect 100 Continue header information. You can see my original post about my issue and how I fixed it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080401/gce-http-load-balancing-returns-error-502-bad-gateway-only-when-posting-vi